# creating windows movie maker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how can create a windows move maker like application in vb.net....

if we want to create a media player than we can i add windows media player in our forms is there any way to add windows movie maker in our forms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't directly embed WMM into a .Net form like you can WMP. You can, however, use the [WMM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb469713%28VS.85%29.aspx) to talk to it, although it seems to be a very limited API.